# if/else statement in a function: using onclick as a switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, onclick

I have looked for solutions to this on google for what seems like an eternity, but I can't seem to formulate my search correctly, or nobody has posted the code I'm looking for earlier.

I am currently trying to make a function that will modify one or several margins of a div element. I want to use an if/else statement within the function, so that the onclick event will switch between the two conditions. This is what I have been working on so far;

```
function facebookToggle()
{
    if($('#facebooktab').style.margin-left == "-250px";)
    {
        document.getElementById("facebooktab").style.marginLeft="0px";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("facebooktab").style.marginLeft="-250px";
    }
}
```

I have tried twisting it around a little, like switching between "marginLeft" and "margin-left", to see if I was just using the wrong terms.. I'm starting to wonder if it might not be possible to combine jQuery and regular javascript? I don't know.. It's all just guesses on my part at this point.

Anyway, I have a div, which is now positioned (fixed) so almost all of it is hidden outside the borders of the browser. I want the margin to change onclick so that it will be fully shown on the page. And when it is shown, I want to be able to hide it again by clicking it.

I might be approaching this in the wrong way, but I really hope someone can help me out, or even tell me another way to get the same results. Thank you for any help you can give me.

You can see it in action at: http://www.torucon.no/test/

(EDIT: By the way, I am a complete javascript novice, I have no experience with javascript prior to this experiment. Please don't be too harsh, as I am aware I probably made some really stupid mistakes in this short code.)

Fixed problem:

```
function facebookToggle() {
var fb = $('#facebooktab'); // save reference to element
if( fb.css('margin-left') === '-250px' ) {
    fb.css('margin-left', '0px');
} else {
    fb.css('margin-left', '-250px');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery object doesn't have a property called `style`, so

```
if($('#facebooktab').style.margin-left == "-250px";)
//                   also remove this semi-colon! ^
```

is going to throw an error. Some options for accessing CSS properties are (1)

```
document.getElementById("facebooktab").style.marginLeft;
```

which you have correctly used, or (2)

```
$('#facebooktab').css('margin-left');
```

Consider being consistent and using the same approach for all three cases. You can assign css properties with jQuery like

```
$('#facebooktab').css('margin-left', '-250px');
```

---

**With these things in mind, here's a suggested rewrite:**

```
function facebookToggle() {
    var fb = $('#facebooktab'); // save reference to element
    if( fb.css('margin-left') === '-250px' ) {
        fb.css('margin-left', '0px');
    } else {
        fb.css('margin-left', '-250px');
    }
}
```

and here's another that uses a predefined CSS class:

```css
#facebooktab {
    margin-left: -250px; /** default state */
}

.no-left-margin {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```js
function facebookToggle() {
    $('#facebooktab').toggleClass('no-left-margin');
}
```

- [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: I don't think I quite understood what you said there. I edited my function, using the latter snippet of yours as a base, but it still doesn't work. I've added my edited code in the original question.

Comment: `if($('#facebooktab').css('margin-left', '-250px')` is an _assignment_. You want a _comparison_ like `if( fb.css('margin-left') === '-250px' )`, as I've posted..

Comment: Using your first suggested rewrite fixed the problem! Thank you very much!
I really hate having to be fed code like this, but hopefully I can learn something from it as well.

(To the reply above: Yeah, haha, I kind of forgot to add the comparison in there. My bad!)

I'm guessing what made it work, was using a variable the way you did. Or well, what do I know.. Anyway, thanks a lot - you really helped me out there. :)

Comment: @AuroraSchmidt Glad to help. Feel free to upvote when possible. I tried to explain why your code was broken in the first half of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library. It is written in JavaScript and its API is in JavaScript. Your event handler could be rewritten as follows:

```
function facebookToggle() {
    var el = document.getElementById('facebooktab');
    if (el)
        el.style.marginLeft = (el.style.marginLeft == '250px' ? 0 : -250) + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mixing jQuery with javascript, you got mixed up. Apart from what paislee's advice. you are do this too.

```
if($('#facebooktab')[0].style.margin-left == "-250px";){
    document.getElementById("facebooktab").style.marginLeft="0px";
}
else    {
    var fb = document.getElementById("facebooktab");
    fb.style.marginLeft="-250px";
}
```